# Cakephp : Creating certificates from a template

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a system for a college which caters for their exams and printing of their certificates in Cakephp 2.1. I have a template of the certificate which i want to adopt as the skeleton where variables like name and grade will be printed on per student. Is it possible to use such a template in cakephp? If yes how? If no, is there any other way i can go about it?

Comment: It is possible, you would like it be a normal HTML file or a PDF?

Comment: either would do but would prefer a PDF, incorporating a template like this one http://melashri.files.wordpress.com/2008/05/ashry-010.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [TCPDF library](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and CakePHP before, with decent results in a very similar thing - producing PDF certificates.

Comment: If you'd like there are also services that would do it for you like http://docraptor.com/ and http://saaspose.com/

Comment: There are lots of free documentation about the subject, try this one as well, http://www.od2dev.be/choosing-the-right-pdf-library-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a html template for the certificate and then use this [CakePDF](https://github.com/ceeram/cakepdf) plugin to generate pdfs from it.

Comment: I have a pdf template where i want variables with name and grade be printed on each certificate per student.